# Transparency Material Gradient not showing in Eevee

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm making a simple material to make lightweight sunrays.  I started off by making a transparency texture to get a nice, soft texture to use as a transparency map. Here's a picture of my node setup:

[image]

In cycles, I get the result I want.

[image]

But in Eevee, it is completely transparent:

[image]

However I figured out how to fix that, by tweaking one value in my shader.

[image]

When I lowered this, the light ray texture would appear, and the lower the value, the bigger it would get.  Finally at zero, it would be the regular size, but it looks completely solid, there is no gradient/soft edge!

[image]

I've already enabled alpha clip for the material, and screen space reflections.  Why isn't this basic material working in eevee?

Comment: that fixed it!  thanks, and feel free to add that as an answer!

Comment: No problem. Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *alpha-blend* instead of *alpha-clip*, or try changing the clip threshold (if using alpha clip). *Alpha-clip* is "all or nothing" when it comes to interpolation, so it can cut things out completely if not set properly.